# UIView animation doesn't work properly inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell, which contains a UIView that is being animated when the TableViewCell's awakeFromNib() is being called.
The animation does work for cells that are called when the TableViewController appears but the cells that are being generated when scrolling don't move at all.
How can I solve this?
[I added an example on Github to demonstrate the issue.](https://github.com/evenwerk/Animation-in-TableView)

**The TableViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 20
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TableViewCell

    return cell
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

**The TableViewCell**

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var animatorCell: UIView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0, options: [.CurveEaseInOut, .Repeat, .Autoreverse], animations: { () -> Void in
        self.animatorCell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 10)
        }, completion: nil)
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but since you are using `dequeueReusableCell`, I guess `awakeFromNib` isn't called. The first cells are initialized using `awakeFromNib`, but the next cells will be the same cells, re-used, so they won't be initialized using `awakeFromNib`. If I'm wrong, and `awakeFromNib` *is* called for the next cells, then I guess your animation is finished before it enters the screen.

Either way, you could try to use something like `tableView(_:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:)`([here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:)) in your tableView, and and call an animation-method on the cell from there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately your suggestion gives the same result as the code above. I moved the code from the TableViewCell to the tableView(willDisplayCell).

Comment: @TimE I'm not good at the whole CGAffine-stuff, so I have no idea what your animation is doing, but keep in mind that when you use your animation-code on the re-used cells (the next 'page'), they will already have done the animation once, in the first page. Maybe you need to reset them to have the same 'starting point' as they had the first time?

Comment: Resetting the animation fixed the problem, thank you!